# Alexa LaunchRequest does not recognize specified invocationName "star port seventy five"

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am following the book "Build Talking Apps" from Pragmatic Programmer and building my first Alexa app.

The application name is "starport travel," but the invocationName is "star port seventy five". This is specified in the en-US.json file, and also is the invocationName on the Alexa Developer Console website. It is an Alexa-hosted skill.

The issue is that after deploying and building my code, when I try to test it through the website, by typing "open star port seventy five", or "star port seventy five", or "star port 75", Alexa responds with: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response."

I double-checked that the locale is "en-US" and the app uses English.

What am I missing?

This is my en-US.json file:

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
          "samples": [
            "huh",
            "what",
            "confused"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "slots": [],
          "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
          "samples": [
            "hello",
            "how are you",
            "say hi world",
            "say hi",
            "hi",
            "say hello world",
            "say hello"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
          "samples": []
        }
      ],
      "types": [],
      "invocationName": "star port seventy five"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my index.js:

```
/* *
 * This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK (v2).
 * Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
 * session persistence, api calls, and more.
 * */
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const i18next = require('i18next');
const languageStrings = require('./languageStrings');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Welcome to Star Port Seventy Five.';
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = handlerInput.t('HELLO_MSG');
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = handlerInput.t('HELP_MSG');

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = handlerInput.t('GOODBYE_MSG');

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
/* *
 * FallbackIntent triggers when a customer says something that doesn’t map to any intents in your skill
 * It must also be defined in the language model (if the locale supports it)
 * This handler can be safely added but will be ingnored in locales that do not support it yet 
 * */
const FallbackIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.FallbackIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = handlerInput.t('FALLBACK_MSG');

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
/* *
 * SessionEndedRequest notifies that a session was ended. This handler will be triggered when a currently open 
 * session is closed for one of the following reasons: 1) The user says "exit" or "quit". 2) The user does not 
 * respond or says something that does not match an intent defined in your voice model. 3) An error occurs 
 * */
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Session ended: ${JSON.stringify(handlerInput.requestEnvelope)}`);
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse(); // notice we send an empty response
    }
};
/* *
 * The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
 * It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers for your intents 
 * by defining them above, then also adding them to the request handler chain below 
 * */
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const speakOutput = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
/**
 * Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
 * stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
 * the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below 
 * */
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        const speakOutput = 'Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.';
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

/**
 * This request interceptor will handle the externalized string values.
 */
const LocalisationRequestInterceptor = {
    process(handlerInput) {
        i18next.init({
            lng: Alexa.getLocale(handlerInput.requestEnvelope),
            resources: languageStrings
        }).then((i18n) => {
            handlerInput.t = (...args) => i18n(...args);
        });
    }
};

/**
 * This handler acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
 * payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
 * defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom 
 * */
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        HelloWorldIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        FallbackIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler)
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler)
    .withCustomUserAgent('sample/hello-world/v1.2')
    .addRequestInterceptors(
        LocalisationRequestInterceptor
    )
    .lambda();
```

This is the JSON Input 1:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": true,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.826ac7d7-0ef0-4574-984c-d92f0f9cbc6f",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.20a7255b-e6b4-4328-aa03-2b0aa6e53b5b"
        },
        "attributes": {},
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AMAR7ONMIGNT44YC3SLVLMAARW5MDRYY6LDIYEMZJVVYDYRFAPQKX3RZBLR736N2JF6HAZSJYLXXF4NZ65MQ3HLGMPJ76KAVIIUUKP6PGTF7SHVWZNHHEGZ7LB2QX3PC57IZ6VFFVWJC5LHGRYNKFGCEIMGK2KTZ7OMGE3ZPMANXSWUEBHAMVOCIG6DVGHMII3KVVHPH2ECL4G6Q5DSTCE3YR6TDLBT2UPHHYVSQCBOQ"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "Viewports": [
            {
                "type": "APL",
                "id": "main",
                "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                "dpi": 213,
                "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                "canRotate": false,
                "configuration": {
                    "current": {
                        "mode": "HUB",
                        "video": {
                            "codecs": [
                                "H_264_42",
                                "H_264_41"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": {
                            "type": "DISCRETE",
                            "pixelWidth": 1280,
                            "pixelHeight": 800
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 346,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 216,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "mode": "HUB",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1280,
            "pixelHeight": 800,
            "dpi": 213,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1280,
            "currentPixelHeight": 800,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Extensions": {
            "available": {
                "aplext:backstack:10": {}
            }
        },
        "Advertising": {
            "advertisingId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "limitAdTracking": true
        },
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.20a7255b-e6b4-4328-aa03-2b0aa6e53b5b"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AMAR7ONMIGNT44YC3SLVLMAARW5MDRYY6LDIYEMZJVVYDYRFAPQKX3RZBLR736N2JF6HAZSJYLXXF4NZ65MQ3HLGMPJ76KAVIIUUKP6PGTF7SHVWZNHHEGZ7LB2QX3PC57IZ6VFFVWJC5LHGRYNKFGCEIMGK2KTZ7OMGE3ZPMANXSWUEBHAMVOCIG6DVGHMII3KVVHPH2ECL4G6Q5DSTCE3YR6TDLBT2UPHHYVSQCBOQ"
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AMAZFZBJRMVDO746EWSGOX3PRO5FSWRAD4W2J5ZOGPVZMBWL76NZK4A3Z6CDHWV7YMQSISWFZH2QGFASJ2PRXCQCCJKBIA2K6XW5NN46XC3O2XYJZ2ZYSPJNVLKQYOHVVPCRAEAY2Y4T7XCS45PJHSRMEW324FXD2SZ3K6GTPO7KFTFPROIEQRWZ3S4WCQ23VXTKOL3REPBRQSCO",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.ExffPoK4dQwcX-LZMfld9tYstnwqrmrNjW_ERpWvm1ZC3PXrEaOBCK65eGLs4PW4CNtmAJMKqFPvUhbWH-ma2bm5U3aA0IZEybmBSj7-CsOvMz61FzWGBNTvueubSjVOabjB0gOGG88ly__ddT-oegi43GUT9ReAGI0A2sMWOQM6UMRQvZFSuPy9v8aRB2Rbxb5mfrNBMtkK2Y7CIo-Vk-YOS0hUy0olvYVDZCqqswP8QnoRGUjVwg31pUDw08OxdJtiwdafn8Ckdpn1RnBEb3BVs0Sf9aLBEQK9AxX7r_yVqcxWw89qgE4RBhZxs7I-bPm6obAfvCSs2fPkcxebRg"
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "LaunchRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.43e7975f-518d-4c5f-8631-b96a810b4ba6",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "timestamp": "2024-01-11T06:17:50Z",
        "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
    }
}
```

JSON Output 1 is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That response means that your backend skill handler code is returning an error.  You need to look at the logs associated with that code to see what's going wrong.  If the skill is Alexa hosted then you can access the logs via the "Code" page in the Alexa dev console, you'll then see a Cloudwatch Logs drop down in the menu bar.  There may be multiple regions shown, it's a case of selecting each one and looking to see where the logs were created (may not be the "default" region).
If not Alexa hosted then if using AWS Lambda go to the Cloudwatch AWS page to find your logs.

Comment: Yep - looks like I have some sort of error. I just bootstrapped a new Alexa project using "ask new" and deployed it and it worked perfectly. So I made a mistake somewhere!!!